# A coworker stole a video game I was selling to a friend while i was working. Should I call police?

Tags: professionalism, colleagues

I work at a McDonald's on night shift. I was selling a PlayStation 3 and some games to one of my coworkers. Another coworker wanted me to sell him the system and games but I held firm that I had promised it to the other one. Later he said how bout just 3 of the 7 games. I said no again and that I would ask the one I was selling it to when she got in if maybe she would sell it to him or maybe I could keep the 3 games and lower selling price. He was upset, mean, even pushy about it said she was just going to resell it anyway and that she had girls, and they don't have a need for it (which I though was sexist) and asked me again saying the price was too low and that games were worth good money and that maybe could he buy just the one. I said no again I told him to just wait for our other coworker.

We got busy with dinner rush and I left the games and system on table in the bag tied up and went to work. (I thought it was ok as we have cameras -  the angle sucks but you can almost see our table there) when my buyer/coworker came in I asked about the games and showed her the 3 he wanted and asked her to sell them to him. My coworker said no, they wanted to keep all the games. He asked for just the one, and she said no again. So we tied the bag again and set to work.

Later she found the bag open and assumed I had opened it since I found a cable in my bag that need to go to her. I told her I hadn't had time and grabbed the cable to give to her, we rediscovered one of the games (the one he obsessed over) was missing. I didn't have a case for this game so it was in a yellow game store sleeve kinda hard to miss.

We confronted him, and he didn't admit anything but wouldn't defend himself either. Normally if you are accused of something and you didn't do it, you would defend yourself, right? He took a break shortly after (which he never does) I called my manager and told him I want to check cameras, but we cannot do that until next day when said manager is there.

We confronted him and the other crew members and told them it needed to show up, I didn't care where, but that if it didn't I would have to phone police. My other crew members emptied their pockets and let me even look in their car (only one drives). Personally I don't care for the game. But the idea you think it is ok to steal from anyone is just wrong. We searched the kitchen, break room, and storage areas in store. He didn't help the rest of us search and acted strange the rest of night and practically ran at closing. I know it's just a game, but should I call the cops?

Comment: I'm sorry for the situation, but what is the question? Can you please avoid elaborated description and emotion in the post and only keep the relevant info?

Comment: I will try..i just want to know should i call the cops?

Comment: Please use paragraphs and proper interpunction (with whitespaces between the sentences) in your text. In current form it is almost completely unreadable and very hard to follow.

Comment: Since you left your propery unattended, anyone could have taken it, or you could have misplaced it in the rush. A security camera on the premesis is intended for real security incidents, not for playing lost and found for someone who unwisely left her property on a table at a McDonald's.

Comment: Not an answer, but some advice for future writing: when you're asking something of someone else, put a line towards the top of what you're asking for.  This helps set the context for the person reading the details to know what they should be focusing on.  For an absurd example, imagine you replaced the last sentence with "Did the person act this way because of how I rejected their offer?"  Suddenly, all those preceding paragraphs have a completely different purpose to be parsed.  This isn't just for workplace questions - any conversation's better served by doing this.

Answer (score 2):

**Wait for the camera evidence and then call the cops.**

I am not sure where you live, but people in uniforms with government authority can be quite convincing at extracting good behavior for a variety of reasons. Camera evidence makes their work rather easy, especially if the criminal is already there, so that is why you should wait on that.

Ideally, a criminal record will also help get rid of the co-worker. McDonald's tends not to like thieves having access to their cash.

It depends on how things work in your jurisdiction, but at least in Canada, it seems fairly common for police to be willing to abandon charges if the goods are returned. A couple people on my dorm floor were thieves and the police just made them return what they stole.

Comment: Thank you then i will wait for footage.i am in GA

Comment: Why wait for the camera video though? Police can obtain that if they need it, but 9/10 times, when cops get involved, people confess stupid nonsense like this instantly.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul I am trying to factor in the cops not really caring enough to follow up over a $50 game. At least in the USA and Canada, the quality of policing can be quite... variable. I've known people who were mugged in downtown areas with cameras and drugged at popular clubs without meaningful follow up. I've also known departments that follow up closely. Not sure what kind of police OP has around them, so as usual, I assume the worst case.

Comment: @MatthewGaiser They may not bother much indeed, but they should make a report. And if that is not enough (aka nothing changes) you can always followup with future evidence, like the camera recording. OP will likely have to go to the police station and make the crime report in person though, this is not a 911 matter. And pro tip if police is reluctant to take your crime seriously is to ask for them to give a refusal in writing and to be polite, but firm about it. Though this is a bit of a tangent and I probably should've just made it into an answer hah :P

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul perhaps a tangent, but probably relevant to OP going forward.

Comment: @KimberlyGuardado Tymoteusz Paul has something here you should read.

Comment: *"McDonald's tends not to like thieves having access to their cash."* - Just as equally McDonalds would like a work place free of drama. My thought is all parties might be dismissed from work since it is wasting a lot of valuable company time.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'm a bit surprised you were not fired for this. My thought is that conducting business transaction while on work schedule would be a huge no-no. Even with the idea that you brought a bag, with the game and console to be sold later could be grounds for dismissal.

I'm not quite sure how much you'll discover with the camera. My thought is don't expect much to be revealed and on top of that your coworker might suddenly stop coming in. There's no way to really say your coworker stole it as the bag was opened and anyone could steal it. Just as equally, the person who wanted to buy it could have stole it just as easily as the person who was trying to persuade you to sell it to him instead. There's no way to put either one as innocent.

What you can do in the future:

1. Don't bring expensive items into the workplace for others to buy. Do the transaction at home or while off company time.
2. Lock your items in a safe place. Trunk of a car, in a locker, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your [Crew Member Policies](https://secure.efficientforms.com/ApplicationPDF/Greenboard/EHX/Client_Specific/STC/Crew.pdf) covers this in the MISUSE OF COMPANY PRODUCT AND/OR EQUIPMENT section

> E. Theft of any kind from the company, **employees** or customers.

I have no idea about law enforcement in your jurisdiction, so can only refer you to other answers/comments.